# Passing parameters from workspace to fit function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

This is the first time I'm trying to use the fittype function to fit a custom curve (Birch-Murnaghan EOS). This is what I've done so far:

```
BM = fittype((3*B0/2*((V0/V).^(7/3)-(V0/V).^(5/3))*(1+(3/4)*(B1-4)*((V0/V).^(2/3)-1))), 'coefficients',{'B0', 'B1'}, 'independent', {'V'});
Pres = fit(V,p,BM);
```

V0 is a constant that I've defined earlier. Data values for pressure(dependent variable), and V(independent variable), have also been defined.

I wish to obtain the values of B0 and B1 through the fitting.

However, I get an error in the fittype function:

```
Undefined function or variable 'B0'.
```

However, that is the coefficient I wish to determine from the fitting. Am I using fittype incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encountering two problems here.

**Firstly**, there a number of element-wise multiplications and divisions you need to change (similarly to the way you are using .^).

**Secondly**, according to the MATLAB documentation [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fittype.html) anonymous functions are used (search for 'Create a fit type using an anonymous function' in the documentation) if you want to pass parameters from the workspace.

Try like this:

```
V = rand(10, 1);
p = rand(10, 1);
V0 = 1;
BM = fittype(@(B0, B1, V) (3*B0/2*((V0./V).^(7/3)-(V0./V).^(5/3)).*(1+(3/4).*(B1-4).*((V0./V).^(2/3)-1))), 'independent', {'V'});
fo = fitoptions( 'Method','NonlinearLeastSquares', 'StartPoint',[1 1]);
Pres = fit(V,p,BM, fo);
```

**Note:** Without specifying a start point for the parameters to be fit you get a warning because MATLAB chooses the start points randomly.

You can access your parameters using dot notation `Pres.B0` or `Pres.B1`.

Comment: Thanks! I am able to run it now, though I still have some questions. It says  "Warning: Start point not provided, choosing random start point."

Edit: I found out I can see the coefficients by just printing 'Pres'. Thanks! Will the random starting point thing still be a problem?

Comment: Many many thanks for responding to my questions, I've learnt a lot!

Comment: No worries, glad I was able to help ;)